# cellForRow At IndexPath executing once too few?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Here's a weird thing that happened to me today:

I'm using a table view to display events for the next 7 days. `numberOfRowsInSection` is hard-coded to always return 7.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 7
}
```

In my cellForRow At IndexPath I'm dequeueing a custom UITableViewCell. I then create a variable called today to hold the current date and print it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let thisWeekCell = thisWeekTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ThisWeekTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier()) as! ThisWeekTableViewCell

let today = Date()
print(today)

return thisWeekCell
}
```

When I run the app, my `UITableView` shows the correct number of cells on the screen (7).
However, the Xcode console only logs the value of my today variable 6 times. That is what freaks me out: It should be called once for each cell, right? So why is there a discrepancy between the number of cells on screen and the number of times the code in `cellForRow` At `IndexPath` gets executed?

Comment: only 6 rows are fitted on the visible screen so 6 times it gets printed, scroll to see the seventh one, and seventh print.

Answer (score 1):

The method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { }
```

Only gets called if the System needs to dequeue a new cell, and this depends on how much cells fits inside the visible bounds of the tableView, so if you can only fit 5 cells in the tableView, it will be called 5 times only

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input guys, I actually just figured out what the problem was.

All 7 cells actually fit within the visible bounds of my TableView, so cellForRowAt should definitely be called 7 times. No scrolling needed.

The problem, it seems, lies within my custom cell class. I used autolayout to calculate the height of my cell instead of giving it a fixed height, but within my cells xib file I didn't add any constraint for the bottom space to the label within the cell. This also led to XCode displaying a "constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view" warning.
As soon as I give the label a bottom space constraint, cellForRowAt gets called 7 times. Weird...

Comment: It's great that you fixed it, but this in no way grows out of the question as you posed it; thus this is not a viable question-and-answer pair.